# how to run pyrogram userbot with multiple user accounts using thread

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I am coding a userbot in pyrogram but I want to run multiple Clients with different telegram account but I am stuck here.
I want to run userbot on multiple accounts using one script if I will run it separately then I have to host it so many time I want to host it for one time and run for every account I have.
I think this will help to understand what I am saying.

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters, handlers, idle
import threading
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler

app1 = Client(
    session, api_hash, api_id)


app2 = Client(session,
              api_hash, api_id)


accounts = [app1, app2]


async def handlngmessage(client, message):
    print(message)
    print("\nstarted ")
    await client.send_message("me", "recived")


def runner(c):
    c.run()


for ac in accounts:
    ac.add_handler(handlers.MessageHandler(unmutedtest))
    t = threading.Thread(target=runner, args=(ac,))
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

When I run this I am just getting error

**Output**:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ak/Desktop/development/bots/pyrogramplugins/userbot/main.py", line 30, in runner
    c.run()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 50, in run
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/ak/Desktop/development/bots/pyrogramplugins/userbot/main.py", line 30, in runner
    c.run()
  File "/home/ak/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 50, in run
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 642, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Pyrogram you don't need to use Threading. The internal code is already entirely asynchronous and you can just start the clients one after another, then call `Client.idle()` to keep them all "alive".

```py
from pyrogram import Client

app1 = Client("first account")
app2 = Client("second account")

# You can either stack decorators ...
@app1.on_message()
@app2.on_message()
async def m_func(_, message):
    pass

# ... or use multiple add_handler calls
app1.add_handler(MessageHandler(m_func))
app2.add_handler(MessageHandler(m_func))

# Then start all Clients and call idle() to keep them running
app1.start()
app2.start()
Client.idle()
app1.stop()
app2.stop()
```

---

Alternatively, here's a Gist with some more explanation.
https://gist.github.com/pokurt/96afa69e86725850b2101099461609ed

Comment: I Am using almost 50 clients so it take a lot of time to start every account.Is there any way to run them parallel which will reduce time and the program will start in less time

Comment: @user14195337 I guess there you can use Threading. Start like 5 Threads with 10 accounts each. To solve 'no current event loop' exception, in every new thread use asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop()) to set event loop for each thread.

Answer (score 0):

pyrogram provides the `compose` feature.
from the docs:

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, compose


async def main():
    apps = [
        Client("account1"),
        Client("account2"),
        Client("account3")
    ]

    ...

    await compose(apps)


asyncio.run(main())
```

[Pyrogram compose](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/compose#compose)